# Proof by induction of summation inequality: $1 + 1/2+ 1/3+ 1/4+1/5+⋯+ 1/2^n \leq n + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I have been working on this problem for literally hours, and I can't come up with anything. Please help. I feel like I am about to go insane.

For all n $\in$ N, we have $$1 + \frac{1}{2}+  \frac{1}{3}+  \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5} +⋯+  \frac{1}{2^n}   ≤ n + 1$$

I know that I am supposed to use a proof by induction. Here is progress so far:

1) Let P(n) be $$\sum_{i=0}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} $$

2) Base case: $n = 1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{2} =  \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2} ≤ 2 $$

So P(1) is true.

3) Inductive hypothesis:
Suppose that P(k) is true for an arbitrary integer k $\geq$ 1

4) Inductive step:
We want to prove that P(k + 1) is true or, $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{i} ≤ k + 2$$

By inductive hypothesis,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{i} + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i} ≤ k + 1 + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}$$

I know that I'm supposed to split the expression into two summations, but now I am completely stuck and don't know what to do from here. I got one hint that the fact $\frac{a}{b + c} < \frac{a}{b}$ is relevant, but I don't know how to get there from here.

Comment: How many terms are in the last sum?  How large is the biggest one?

Comment: Last sum will have 2^(k+1)-(2^k +1), or 2^(k+1)-2^k-1 terms, right? When I try to work with that I just get a huge mess.

Comment: How many terms are there from $7,8,....,12$.  Is it $12-7$ or is it $12 - 6$?  And What is $2^{k+1} - 2^k$ or $2^{k+1} - 2^k - 1$. Do you know what $2^{k+1} -2^k$ is?  Hint:  It is not a huge mess.  It is not a mess at all.  Hint 2:  Doe $2^{k+1} - 2^k$ have a term you can factor out.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \ge 2$, we have $$\frac{1}{n} \le \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
So, $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}{\frac{1}{i}} \leq 1+\int_{1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{x}\,dx=1+k \log2 \le 1+k$$  Another proof:as your progress $$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{1+2^k}+\frac{1}{2+2^k}+...+\frac{1}{2^k+2^k}\le\frac{2^k}{1+2^k}\le1$$

Answer (score 0):

If $2^k + 1 \le i \le 2^{k+1}$ then $\frac 1i < \frac 1{2^k}$

So $\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}< \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{2^k} =[2^{k+1} - ([2^k + 1]-1)\times \frac 1{2^k} =   2^k\times \frac 1{2^k} = 1$